# How to Remove Patients with Less Than 2 Visits of Data

Tags: r, subset, panel-data

I have a longitudinal dataset structured as 1 row per visit.
A numerical patient ID number indicates unique patients.

How can I remove all patients with less than 2 observations from my dataset?

So for this example I want to remove the rows with patient **105** and **110**.

Example

```
Patient ID   Disease Score
101             5
101             2
101             2
105             1
110             5
115             1
115             1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dat <- read.table(text="Patient ID,Disease Score
101,5
101,2
101,2
105,1
110,5
115,1
115,1", stringsAs=FALSE, header=TRUE, sep=",")

# one way in base
dat[dat$Patient.ID %in% names(which(table(dat$Patient.ID)>2)),]

# one way in dplyr
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(Patient.ID) %>%
  mutate(n=n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(n>=2) %>%
  select(Patient.ID, Disease.Score)
```

Comment: I was about to suggest: `dat %>% group_by(Patient.ID) %>% summarise(Disease.Score = sum(Disease.Score)) %>% filter(Disease.Score >= 2)`

Comment: Thank you hrbrmstr, the example from the base way worked very well.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré I didn't know if @Mark needed the actual individual records or not (and erred on the side of him needing them). Completely agree that `summarise` would be more optimal just to identify the >=2 records.